# for-loop does not output with order

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a df that contains the hi, low, close, EMA200, etc...

When I run this for loop I get something really weird:

```
for i in range(100,len(price)):
    max_idx = list(argrelextrema(hi.values[:i], np.greater, order=7)[0])
    min_idx = list(argrelextrema(lo.values[:i], np.less, order=7)[0])

    if (df["close"][i] > df["EMA50"][i] > df["EMA100"][i] > df["EMA200"][i] 
        and  price[min_idx][-1] <  price[max_idx][-1]
        and df["CDLENGULFING"][i] != 0):

        print("fdbffd")

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))
        plt.plot(price.index[i-200:i+200],price.values[i-200:i+200])
```

Please look at the picture to see what the for loop outputs.

First, it prints the 5 prints that meet the criteria and after the 5 graphs.

[image]

Does anyone know why it prints all the "print" values first and after the graphs?

Comment: May be because you have plt.show() outside the for loop

Comment: I did not have plt.show() at all and now that I did put it inside it works! Thanks a lot!